# Verificar data conforme serial

Tags: php, javascript

Uma duvida que tenho sobre o preenchimento do mês, de acordo com o numero de série preenchido.

A lógica esta no 4º e 5º dígitos da licença, que são um numero hexadecimal

Exemplo :  0AC**19**2F4B16EA6A5CE

- O número  19, significa que vencerá em 30/01/2018
- O número  1A, significa que vencerá em 28/02/2018
- O número  1B, significa que vencerá em 30/03/2018

Minha duvida é a seguinte, é possivel uma regra php ou algum script que possa preencher o mês ao inserir a licença no campo do formulário?

Comment: Creio que sim, vc joga os valores conhecidos em um array e depois compara e exibe.... Tens algo começado ?

Comment: Imagino que tem um calculo aí para definir a data de vencimento da licença só o `19`/`1A` ou `1B` não é suficiente para descobrir.

Comment: Em SQL-SERVER seria assim: SELECT DATEADD(month, o_numero_hexa_em_decimal, '2015-12-30'); é igual a data de vencimento.

Comment: @Bacco o que estou fazendo é um cadastro dos clientes, revendemos um sistema de ERP para comercio, e a empresa não me passa como gerou a senha, só me informou a forma de achar o mes de vencimento na licenca, então o que estou na duvida se usar o array para ler o 4º e 5º numero da chave assim xxx19xxxxxxxxxxxxxx. Desculpe aos maus entendidos a pergunta na fomrulação

Comment: A Chave  é criada com informações do CNPJ do cliente + o mes de pedido  e o numero de serie do equipamento. O que estou fazendo é um controle meu de vencimentos no mes, gerando um relatório

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quer saber a data, basta isso:

```
function VencimentoSerial($serial) {
   $vencto = strtotime( '2016-1-1 +'.hexdec(substr($serial, 3, 2)).' months last day');
   return gmdate( 'd/m/Y', $vencto);
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/smPWn6)**.